# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod Paging

Tags: powershell, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to get a list of all users from our Azure B2C tenant.

With some help from the internet I was able to create the powershell script below. But the result is incomplete it only shows 100 users. After searching around I found I should probably do something with Paging but I can't get it to work.

Can someone help me to modify the script below to return all users?

```
# Application (client) ID, tenant Name and secret
$clientId = "**********"
$tenantName = "*********"
$clientSecret = "************"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"


$ReqTokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_Id     = $clientID
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
} 

$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody


$Url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName"
$Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $Url -Method Get
$Users = ($Data |select-object Value).Value

$Users | Format-Table DisplayName -AutoSize
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: I am using Powershell version 5.1.19041.1023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got it to work in Powershell Core (Version 7.1.3).

This is the code I ended up using.

```
# Application (client) ID, tenant Name and secret
$clientId = "**************"
$tenantName = "***************"
$clientSecret = "******************"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"


$ReqTokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_Id     = $clientID
    Client_Secret = $clientSecret
} 

$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody

$Url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName"
$UserResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $Url -Method Get -Verbose

$CloudUser = $UserResponse.Value
$UserNextLink = $UserResponse."@odata.nextLink"

while ($UserNextLink -ne $null) {

    $UserResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"} -Uri $UserNextLink -Method Get -Verbose)
    $UserNextLink = $UserResponse."@odata.nextLink"
    $CloudUser += $UserResponse.value
}

$CloudUser | Format-Table DisplayName -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the last 8 lines (or so) are repeated. You can factor it out like this:

```
$Url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName"
$headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse.access_token)"}
$CloudUser = @()
do {
    $UserResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri $Url -Method Get -Verbose
    $CloudUser += $UserResponse.Value
    $Url = $UserResponse."@odata.nextLink"
} while ($Url)
```

Also, why not use the Graph PowerShell module for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph